# Does the series $1-\frac12+\frac12-\frac1{2^2}+\frac13-\frac1{2^3}+\frac14-\frac1{2^4}+\frac15-\frac1{2^5}+\cdots$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{2^5}+\cdots$

I've be trying to figure out how to write this series symbolically so I can examine it's limit, but I'm having trouble.  So far the best I've come up with is:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)$

But obviously the above does not properly reproduce the series.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: the terms are not monotonically decreasing.

Comment: @CameronWilliams but I can't because the series is increasing

Comment: Brain fart! My bad! I didn't notice the 1/n terms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the terms go to $0$, the series can be rewritten as
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1k-\frac1{2^k}\right)\tag{1}
$$
Since
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1k-\frac1{2^k}\right)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2^k}\\[3pt]
&\ge\log(n+1)-1\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
the limit in $(1)$ does not exist.

Comment: As part of my learning experience, is my answer valid (followed by Ahmed's concerns?) Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: @imranfat: the reason I considered partial sums is because of the concern posed by Ahmed Hussein. Using finite sums avoids rearranging infinite sums; however, the idea in your answer is good, but there are 't's that should be crossed.

Comment: I see. The series in question is a "combination" of a divergent series (positive terms) and an absolute convergent series (negative terms). Is there an counter example of such a series that would be convergent, thus invalidating my argument? I could see my answer to be invalid, if the positive term and negative terms both would be conditionally convergent, which is not the case here)

Comment: @imranfat: no (in fact, I upvoted your answer), but care must be taken in separating the series. One way to make the argument sound would be to assume that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{2^k}\right)$$ converged. Then, because the terms are positive, the series converges absolutely. Now, add the absolutely convergent series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2^k}$$ to get that the series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k$$ converges. Contradiction.

Comment: @imranfat See my answer. It answers your question in the comment (I think). :)

Comment: @robjohn, Thanks, then I know my answer is right at least for this problem, due to the nature of the two separate series.

Comment: @awllower. This makes sense indeed. Because one series is absolute convergent and the other is divergent, their combination will be divergent.

Comment: @imranfat: a result can be correct even though the reasoning used in achieving it is flawed.

Comment: @robjohn. Yes, that ain't a good thing. Thanks for the prompt replies...

Comment: @robjohn Well actually the series can't be written that way, because we don't know the limit exists, and even if it did, it would still not be correct. A series doesn't equal a limit. Much better to say $S_{2n}$ equals that. Then proceed to argue  $S_{2n}$ diverges, hence by definition, the series diverges.

Comment: @zhw: since the terms go to $0$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_{2n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n$ if either exists.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that $$S_{n}=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\left\lceil \frac{n}{2}\right\rceil\left(\dfrac{1}{i}\right)-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\left(\dfrac{1}{2^i}\right)\ge\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil\dfrac{1}{i}\right)-1$$ Since the sequence of partial sum diverges, the series also diverges.

Answer (score 3):

When you look at the terms with the positive signs, it is the Harmonic Series, so that's divergent. Looking at the negative terms, it is essentially a geometric series, factor $1/2$ so that's (absolutely) convergent. Putting them together results in a divergent series.
EDIT: I made the assumption that terms can be rearranged without affecting the sum of the series. One should take caution with this as this CAN change the outcome of the series' sum. In particular when the series of both positive and negative terms are represented by conditionally convergent series. However, in this case, we have a divergent series represented by the positive terms, against a absolute convergent series, represented by the negative terms. In such a situation (after little research) the result will always be a divergent series.

Comment: This is not quite right. You are basically rearranging the series, which is invalid (did not down vote)

Comment: @AhmedHussein. Why is it invalid in this problem?

Comment: To rearrange a series, you must have absolute convergence

Comment: One of the series is absolute convergent. The divergent series is not going to affect the outcome, still divergent. Rearranging becomes an issue when dealing with conditionally convergent series. It doesn't apply here since the positives are divergent and the negatives are not. This series will always be divergent

Answer (score 1):

Denote the series as $a_n;$ then clearly $\sum \mid a_n\ \mid$ is divergent. So, if $\sum a_n$ converges, then it is a conditionally convergent series.
By [Riemann's rearrangement theorem on page 7](https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_14/history%20of%20rearrangements.pdf), we can write $$\sum a_n=\sum a_n^++\sum a_n^-$$ without rearranging the terms, where $$a_n^+=max(a_n,0),\quad a^-_n=min(a_n,0).$$

And, if $\sum a_n$ is conditionally convergent, then both $\sum a_n^+$ and $\sum a_n^-$ are divergent. But clearly $\sum a_n^-=\sum -\frac{1}{2^n}$ converges, so $\sum a_n$ is not conditionally convergent, and hence $\sum a_n$ diverges.

Hope this helps.

**P.S.**

In fact we can write explicitly:
$$\begin{align}a_{2n-1}^+&=\frac{1}{n}\\
a_{2n}^+&=0\\
a_{2n-1}^-&=0\\
a_{2n}^-&=\frac{-1}{2^{n}}\end{align}$$